# How to copy data from one table to another using one by one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to copy the data from the `Player` table to the `User` table.

Here's my `Player` table:

```
Name     Age  City
---------------------
pavan    27   Delhi
Kishor   29   Delhi
pavan    30   Delhi
```

I want to insert this data into the `User` table which has these columns:

```
Name    Age    Active
```

Now I want that there should be only one active name.

Rest all duplicate entries should be marked inactive (active = 0)

I tried this query, but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO User (name, age, active)
    SELECT 
        name, age,
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM User u WHERE u.name = name) 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
        END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `there should be only one unique active name` ... what is the logic determining whose name gets assigned to active?

Comment: the second pavan should be marked as inactive because it's the duplicate one in the table.

Comment: First, `USER` is a reserved word, so you cannot use it as table name in this way. Second, you missed up a `FROM` clause in your `SELECT`. It would be `Insert into User (name,age,active)
SELECT name, age,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM User u WHERE u.name = name) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Player`. Rename your `User` table and all should work

Comment: Which one is the "second" Pavan? Is the second one always the elder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a CTE here first to make the selection of which name record is set to active more deterministic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM Player
)

INSERT INTO [User] (name, age, active)
SELECT name, age, CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM cte;
```

Comment: yourTable will replace the user table?

Comment: @pavankumar Sorry... `yourTable` should have been `Player`, answer updated.

Comment: this rn is unreachable

Comment: If you cut and paste _all_ of my SQL code, dump it into SSMS, and run it, it should work.  The only thing I can think of is that maybe you aren't running the CTE with the insert query below it.

Comment: I got another problem here because I want to copy data now from Doctor table.
so how can i do it. because now i have to check on both table user(having existing data) and on Doctor table.

Is there a way by which i can select and insert row one by one only.?

Comment: Simple solution: You open a new question `:-)`